# Product Variants - Frontend

Tags: shopware

I defined in the backend of shopware a product p as variant product: I defined the base product and all variants of that product p1, p2, ..., pn.

Well I can see in the frontend that there are n version of p available. When I select another version of p, say p3, then the loader symbol gets stuck.

Does anyone know how could I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe you can provide link? In any case problem can be in JS or server side. You need define what exactly problem you have. You can start from checking server log and shopware log(`SOPWARE_ROOT_INSTALLATION/var/log`)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the debug configuration in your `config.php`, like this: http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1961.html

Than you can provide us a more detailed error message and we can help you. Further you can check the log file which was already mentioned by alexey. If it is a JavaScript error you could take a look in the developer console of your browser to see JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Ajax request is cancelled. It can happen if you have an script error or maybe you article isn't set correctly. Make a screenshot of the Article settings and console, maybe than we'll able to help you :)